# Overriding CSS dynamically from javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, typescript

I am trying to create a horizontal scroll bar based on the example given here:

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_rangeslider.asp

My question has to do with the width of the moving slider (only the moving element of the object). Just to make myself more clear, I am uploading a screen shot of the slider I have created so far, in which I have circled the element, the width of which i am trying to change: [Slider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBpAG.jpg)

Is there a way to override the CSS property and change the width dynamically, depending on the input data?

What i have tried to do so far, based on similar questions i found, is to change the width using webkit. Unfortunately it is not working:

```
 elem.before($('<div class="slidecontainer"><input type="range" id="mySlider" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider"></div>'));
 slider = _.find($('[id="mySlider"]'));
 slider = $(slider);
 document.getElementById('mySlider').style.webkitTransform = '{width: 250 px}';
```

Below you can also find a picture with the css property I would like to change dynamically: [CSS File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bokfT.jpg)

Any advice would be very helpful. Thank you in advance!

Comment: looks like you are using jQuery?  if so why not just use `$('#mySlider').width('250px')`? http://api.jquery.com/width/#width2

Comment: @Pete 

Thank you for the reply! I have tried, what you proposed me. The problem is that this will change the width of the whole slider. I want to change the width of the moving element only!

Comment: Right, and per the documentation you reference, you need to change the width of the "slider" element which is the "class" attribute in the element.  So `$('.slider').width('250px')`

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```js
document.body.innerHTML = '<div class="slidecontainer"><input type="range" id="mySlider" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider"></div>'

document.querySelector('#mySlider').style.width = '250px';

setTimeout(() => {
  document.querySelector('#mySlider').style.width = '100px';
},3000)
```

You were doing much more then needed. Just set the `style.width` on your element.

**UPDATE** The best way, today, to change just the slider thumb is to use CSS variables:

```js
document.body.innerHTML = '<div class="slidecontainer"><input type="range" id="mySlider" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider"></div>'

document.querySelector('#mySlider').style.setProperty('--thumb-width', '55px');

setTimeout(() => {
  document.querySelector('#mySlider').style.setProperty('--thumb-width', '155px');
},3000)
```

```css
#mySlider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  background: #d3d3d3;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

#mySlider:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

#mySlider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  background: #FF0000;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 25px;
  outline: none;
  width: var(--thumb-width, 25px);
}



#mySlider::-moz-range-thumb {
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  background: #FF0000;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 25px;
  outline: none;
  width: var(--thumb-width, 25px);
}

#mySlider::-ms-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  background: #FF0000;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 25px;
  outline: none;
  width: var(--thumb-width, 25px);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I appreciate it. queryselector might not be working with style property (an error comes up), but my main problem is that this will change the width of the whole slider. I would like to change the width of the moving element only!

Comment: Thank you again! This is exactly what i was looking for. I will try to implement what you are proposing on my code and come back again with feedback.

Comment: My apologies for the late answer. 
I used CSS variables and it is working fine with me. 
Thank you again!